# How to do a mysql select query on a table with two columns of foreign keys that relate to another table of names

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

I have two tables, Table A has two foreign key columns (`div_player1_id`, `div_player2_id`) and `Table B` has a Primary key that relates to the foreign keys in `Table A`. I am trying to write a select query that will output the names of `player1` and `player 2` in one row.

```
wp_divisions - Div_id, div_player1_id, div_player2_id
wp_players - ID, display_name

Output = Div_Id, display_name of Player1, display_name of Player2
```

---

```
Select display_name FROM wp_players INNER Join wp_divisions where wp_players.ID = wp_divisions.div_player1_id;
```

This shows the Player1 names.

```
Select display_name FROM wp_players INNER Join wp_divisions where wp_players.ID = wp_divisions.div_player2_id;
```

This shows Player2 name.

I would like to have the output in a Table with:

```
Division    Player 1     Player 2
  1001     Joe Smith     Tom Jones
```

I tried following [Table with two foreign keys pointing to the same column of another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280591/table-with-two-foreign-keys-pointing-to-the-same-column-of-another-table)

But could not adapt it to my needs

Not sure how to write the code.

Comment: (Obviously--) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Explain about how you "could not adapt it to my needs". And what about the many, many other duplicates?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get matching data from another SQL table for two different columns: Inner Join and/or Union?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682228/how-to-get-matching-data-from-another-sql-table-for-two-different-columns-inner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must join `wp_divisions` with `wp_players` twice:

```
select
  d.Div_id,
  p1.display_name player1,
  p2.display_name player2
from wp_divisions d
inner join wp_players p1 on p1.ID = d.div_player1_id
inner join wp_players p2 on p2.ID = d.div_player2_id
```

If there is a case that `div_player1_id` or `div_player2_id` is `null` then use `left` joins instead of `inner` joins.

Comment: Worked perfectly. to add onto this, if d.div_player2_id = 0, then Set d.div_player2_id = 125; 

select
  d.player_div_id AS Division,
  p1.display_name player1,
  p2.display_name player2
from wp_divisions d
inner join wp_players p1 on p1.ID = d.div_player1_id
inner join wp_players p2 on p2.ID = d.div_player2_id
WHERE IF (d.div_player2_id IS 0, d.div_player2_id IS 125); Fails

Comment: What is `WHERE IF (d.div_player2_id IS 0, d.div_player2_id IS 125)`? Use `WHERE d.div_player2_id = 0 AND d.div_player2_id = 125)`

Comment: It was meant to replace a 0 with 125

Comment: In Table wp_divisions are Player 1 and Player 2. For Singles Player 2 has an ID of 0. For Doubles there is a Player 2 ID other than 0. The ealier slect string works perfect for when it is Doubles, but when it is Singles no information is found. I created a Player id 125 that has a display_name = blank.

Comment: This Singles and Doubles is something that you may understand, but I don't. I can't see how a table design where the same player has 2 different ids would work. This answer has the code relating to your question as you posted it. If the requirement is different post a new question and explain what you want.

Comment: It was related to Tennis. Singles and Doubles players and each player has their own player id. Thank you very much. You answered my question.